# How to add shortcuts to HTML files to Win8/Win2012 Start Menu without UAC?

Tags: windows-8, shortcuts, uac, windows-server-2012, start-screen

I have a Windows 2012 server joined to a domain with UAC disabled by group policy. I'm logged on as a domain user with local admin rights.

I create a shortcut to a local HTML file, then I add that shortcut to C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs. The shortcut appears in Start screen, but when I click on it, I get a dreadful message: "This app can't open - Internet Explorer cannot open while User Access Control is turned off". Of course IE works just fine on its own, and the same shortcut placed on desktop works fine as well.

I'm not sure if I want to know why this is happening (although clear explanations of the byzantine UAC system are always welcome), but I'd certainly like to know how to launch this sort of shortcuts from Start menu without having to enable UAC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be by design. See: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2736601

Does setting Internet Explorer to open links on the desktop change the behaviour?

Comment: Winner: Internet Options -> Programs -> Choose how you open links: Always in Internet Explorer on the desktop. Thanks!